# Why updating "shallow" copy dictionary doesn't update "original" dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

While reading up the documentation for `dict.copy()`, it says that it makes a shallow copy of the dictionary. Same goes for the book I am following (Beazley's Python Reference), which says:

> The m.copy() method makes a shallow
>   copy of the items contained in a
>   mapping object and places them in a
>   new mapping object.

Consider this:

```
>>> original = dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> new = original.copy()
>>> new.update({'c': 3})
>>> original
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> new
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

So I assumed this would update the value of `original` (and add 'c': 3) also since I was doing a shallow copy. Like if you do it for a list:

```
>>> original = [1, 2, 3]
>>> new = original
>>> new.append(4)
>>> new, original
([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This works as expected.

Since both are shallow copies, why is that the `dict.copy()` doesn't work as I expect it to? Or my understanding of shallow vs deep copying is flawed?

Comment: Quaint that they don't explain "shallow". Insider knowledge, wink. Just the dict and keys are a copy while nested dicts inside that first level are references, cannot be deleted in a loop for example. Thus Python's dict.copy() in that case is neither useful nor intuitive. Thanks for your question.

Comment: "Since both are shallow copies" - that's the issue here. The second example **is not** a copy, shallow or otherwise.

Answer (score 1275, accepted):

By "shallow copying" it means the *content* of the dictionary is not copied by value, but just creating a new reference.

```
>>> a = {1: [1,2,3]}
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> a, b
({1: [1, 2, 3]}, {1: [1, 2, 3]})
>>> a[1].append(4)
>>> a, b
({1: [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {1: [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

In contrast, a deep copy will copy all contents by value.

```
>>> import copy
>>> c = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> a, c
({1: [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {1: [1, 2, 3, 4]})
>>> a[1].append(5)
>>> a, c
({1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, {1: [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

So:

1. `b = a`: Reference assignment, Make `a` and `b` points to the same object.

   [image: Illustration of 'a = b': 'a' and 'b' both point to '{1: L}', 'L' points to '[1, 2, 3]'.]
2. `b = a.copy()`: Shallow copying, `a` and `b` will become two isolated objects, but their contents still share the same reference

   [image: Illustration of 'b = a.copy()': 'a' points to '{1: L}', 'b' points to '{1: M}', 'L' and 'M' both point to '[1, 2, 3]'.]
3. `b = copy.deepcopy(a)`: Deep copying, `a` and `b`'s structure and content become completely isolated.

   [image: Illustration of 'b = copy.deepcopy(a)': 'a' points to '{1: L}', 'L' points to '[1, 2, 3]'; 'b' points to '{1: M}', 'M' points to a different instance of '[1, 2, 3]'.]

Comment: Nice answer, but you might consider correcting the grammatical error in your first sentence. And there's no reason to not use `L` again in `b`. Doing so would simplify the example.

Comment: @kennytm: What is the difference between the first two examples, in fact? You get there the same result, but slightly different inner implementation, but for what does it matter?

Comment: @TomRussell: Or anybody, since this question is quite old, my clarification question is for everybody

Comment: @JavaSa It matters if, say, you do `b[1][0] = 5`. If `b` is a shallow copy, you've just changed `a[1][0]`.

Comment: @TomRussell: I meant first two examples from drawings, not text, my mistake, so question is still valid

Comment: @JavaSa `a[1] = {}` will affect `b` in the first example, and won't affect `b` in the second example.

Comment: @kennytm `a[1] = {}` *doesn't* affect `b` in the first example. I leave it to you to explain how this is. :-)

Comment: @TomRussell Just to clarify, "first example" means the first example in the picture (i.e. `b = a` instead of `b = a.copy()`).

Comment: @kennytm Ah, bummer. You anticipated my objection exactly. IIRC, I thought we going to get to have an interesting discussion about the semantics of copying a list object vs the items in it. :-(

Comment: Great explanation,... really saved my day! Thanks...Can this same be applied tp the list, str, and other datatypes of python?

Comment: @Bhuro Yes to `list`, no to `str` (a Python string is immutable so this doesn't matter).

Comment: a=[[[1,2,3]]],id(a[0][0]) != id(copy.deepcopy(a)[0][0])

Comment: Plus one for nice visualization.

Comment: @kennytm : `dic_a = {'A': 'Apple', 'B': 'Ball'}` and `dic_b = dic_a`, then `dic_b['A'] = 'Adam'` changes the value in both dictionaries. But when `dic_b = dic_a.copy()`, then doing `dic_b['A'] = 'Adam'` changes the value of `A` only in `dic_b`. Why does the value change in the first case when strings are immutable?

Comment: @Sheldore `dic_a` and `dic_b` are referencing the same dictionary when you `dic_b = dic_a`. The strings in the dictionary are immutable but that's irrelevant, because `dic_b['A'] = 'Adam'` mutates the dictionary itself.

Answer (score 51):

Take this example:

```
original = dict(a=1, b=2, c=dict(d=4, e=5))
new = original.copy()
```

Now let's change a value in the 'shallow' (first) level:

```
new['a'] = 10
# new = {'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 4, 'e': 5}}
# original = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 4, 'e': 5}}
# no change in original, since ['a'] is an immutable integer
```

Now let's change a value one level deeper:

```
new['c']['d'] = 40
# new = {'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 40, 'e': 5}}
# original = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'d': 40, 'e': 5}}
# new['c'] points to the same original['d'] mutable dictionary, so it will be changed
```

Comment: `no change in original, since ['a'] is an immutable integer` This. It actually answers the question asked.

Comment: The fact that integers are immutable is not the reason the original is unchanged. You could observe the same behaviour when using mutable objects instead of 1 and 10 as the values.

Answer (score 42):

It's not a matter of deep copy or shallow copy, none of what you're doing is deep copy.

Here:

```
>>> new = original
```

you're creating a new reference to the the list/dict referenced by original.

while here:

```
>>> new = original.copy()
>>> # or
>>> new = list(original) # dict(original)
```

you're creating a new list/dict which is filled with a copy of the references of objects contained in the original container.

Comment: True, as far as it goes... but it doesn't go far enough to answer the OP question about shallow vs. deep.

Answer (score 12):

Adding to kennytm's answer. When you do a shallow copy ***parent.copy()*** a new dictionary is created with same keys,but the values are not copied they are referenced.If you add a new value to ***parent_copy*** it won't effect ***parent*** because ***parent_copy*** is a new dictionary not reference.

```
parent = {1: [1,2,3]}
parent_copy = parent.copy()
parent_reference = parent

print id(parent),id(parent_copy),id(parent_reference)
#140690938288400 140690938290536 140690938288400

print id(parent[1]),id(parent_copy[1]),id(parent_reference[1])
#140690938137128 140690938137128 140690938137128

parent_copy[1].append(4)
parent_copy[2] = ['new']

print parent, parent_copy, parent_reference
#{1: [1, 2, 3, 4]} {1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: ['new']} {1: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

The hash(id) value of ***parent[1]***, ***parent_copy[1]*** are identical which implies  [1,2,3] of ***parent[1]*** and ***parent_copy[1]*** stored at id 140690938288400.

But hash of ***parent*** and ***parent_copy*** are different which implies 
They are different dictionaries and ***parent_copy*** is a new dictionary having values reference to values of ***parent***

Answer (score 5):

"new" and "original" are different dicts, that's why you can update just one of them.. The *items* are shallow-copied, not the dict itself.

Answer (score 3):

In your second part, you should use `new = original.copy()`

`.copy` and `=` are different things.

Answer (score 2):

*Contents* are shallow copied.

So if the original `dict` contains a `list` or another `dictionary`, modifying one them in the original or its shallow copy will modify them (the `list` or the `dict`) in the other.