# Instance of attributes in an Object

Tags: python, class, object, instance

I have the following concern in Python:

```
a = 1
b = a
b = 2
print(a)
```

From what I understand, `b` is a new variable that uses the value of `a`. Thus, when the value of `b` is changed, that does not affect `a`. So, `print(a)` should yield `1`.

```
class Object:
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 0

a = Object()
a.value = 1
b = a
b.value = 2
print(a.value)
```

However, in this instance, `a` would print `2`. Why is this? How do I make it so that `a.value` will still be `1` instead of `2`?

Comment: In the first case, you're _rebinding_ `b` (i.e. `b = ...`) to a different object than what `a` is bound to. In the second case, you're _mutating_ the object that both `a` and `b` are bound to.

Comment: You can use `copy.deepcopy()` [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794244/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-python) this answer.

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in cmd, set `b = a` and then run:

```
repr(a)
repr(b)
assert(a == b) # is True
```

They are at the same memory address. Now run:

```
c = Object() 
repr(c)
assert(a == c) # is False
assert(b == c) # is False
```

You can see they are different.