# Strange behavior with DataFrame copy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this code:

```
In [16]: data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
Out[18]: 
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
1     Bob   12
2  Clarke   13

In [19]: df_new = df
In [20]: df_new['Age'] = df_new['Age'] * 90 / 100

In [21]: df_new
     Name   Age
0    Alex   9.0
1     Bob  10.8
2  Clarke  11.7

In [22]: df
     Name   Age
0    Alex   9.0
1     Bob  10.8
2  Clarke  11.7
```

When I assigned new values to the *Age* columns of the new DataFrame (*df_new*), the *Age* column of the original DataFrame (*df*) changed as well.

Why does it happen? Does it have something to do with the way I create a copy of the original DataFrame? Seem like they are chained together.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Comment: need `df_new = df.copy()`, check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46939443)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
df_new = df.copy()
```

OR

```
df_new = df.copy(deep=True)
```

This is the standard way of making a copy of a `pandas` object’s indices and data.

From the [`pandas documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

> When deep=True (default), a new object will be created with a copy of
>   the calling object’s data and indices. Modifications to the data or
>   indices of the copy will not be reflected in the original object

**Explanation**

If you see the object IDs of the various DataFrames you create, you can clearly see what is happening.

When you write df_new = df, you are creating a variable named `new_df`, and binding it with an object with same id as that of `df`.

**Example**

```
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])

df_new = df
df_copy = df.copy()
print("ID of old df: {}".format(id(df)))
print("ID of new df: {}".format(id(df_new)))
print("ID of copy df: {}".format(id(df_copy)))
```

**Output**

```
ID of old df: 113414664
ID of new df: 113414664
ID of copy df: 113414832
```