# How to create an object with same contents as another object in python?

Tags: python, class, object

Look at code in my python file:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Create a new point at the origin """
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
p = Point()
p.x = 4
p.y = 4
```

I want to create another object `q` which contains all the values of `p`

Yes,we can do it like this: `q = Point.objects.create(q.x = p.x,q.y = p.y)`

But, I don't want to refer to all the variables inside the class `Point`

How can I do it ?

Comment: You mean clone/copy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794244/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-python https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a copy of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794244/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import copy
```

for a shallow copy use

```
p2 = copy.copy(p)
```

for a deep copy use

```
p2 = copy.deepcopy(p)
```