# why did the value of item2 change?

Tags: python-3.x, function, random

Why did the value of `item2` change after line 20?  No where in the code have I redefined `item2` so my expectation is it should not change.  Is there any way to run the same code without changing the value of `item2`?  Here is my code:

```
import  random   

def one(length):
    a = []
    for i in range(length):
        a.append(1)
    return(a)

def two(parent):
    b = parent
    if random.randint(0,10)<11:
        index = random.randint(0,6)
        b[index] = 6
    return b

item1 = one(6)
print(item1)
item2 = item1
print(item2)
item3 = two(item1)
print(item2)
```

And this is the result I'm getting:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1]

[1,1,1,1,1,1]

[1,6,1,1,1,1]
```

Comment: This should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794244/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-python

Comment: To fix use `b = parent[:]`

Comment: `if random.randint(0,10)<11:` is the same as `if True:`

Comment: @Rakesh   b = parent[:]  worked  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `b = parent`
to `b = parent[:]`
in line 10,
answer provided by @rakesh

Comment: this worked perfectly,  still dont understand why though (anyway it did the job)