# Copying selenium options

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have

```
profile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

I want to create copies of it and modify them differently to obtain a set of different profiles. However, when I do

```
profile1 = profile
profile1.add_argument(different argument)
```

the new arguments seem to be added to the original options and I end up with only 1 set of options. How can I copy the options properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794244/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import copy` then use `copy.deepcopy()`