# Python copy object with monkey patched instance method

Tags: python, monkeypatching

After monkey patching an instance method (using `types.MethodType`) I pass the monkey patched object to a library which copies it (using `copy.copy`) and calls the monkey patched method. The monkey patched method gets called successfully but the `self` parameter references to the old (not copied object).

```py
import copy
import types


class Person:
    def __init__(self, lang):
        self.lang = lang

    def hello(self, n):
        print(id(self), f"{n} times hello in {self.lang}")


def mean_hello(self, n):
    print(id(self), f"{n} times mean hello in {self.lang}")


a = Person('English')
b = copy.copy(a)
b.lang = "French"
print(id(a), id(b))  # 139885310130440 139885310130720
a.hello(1)  # 139885310130440 1 times hello in English
b.hello(1)  # 139885310130720 1 times hello in French

a.hello = types.MethodType(mean_hello, a)
c = copy.copy(a)
c.lang = 'German'
print(id(a), id(c))  # 139885310130440 139885310130664
a.hello(2)  # 139885310130440 2 times mean hello in English
c.hello(2)  # 139885310130440 2 times mean hello in English
```

From the example it can be seen that the last line `c.hello(2)` calls the monkey patched method with `self` referencing to `a`. Why does this happen? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Please be aware that putting callables onto objects does not make them methods – methods are specifically either functions on a class *to be* accessed through an instance (unbound method), or functions on a class *that are* accessed through an instance (bound method). ``types.MethodType(mean_hello, a)`` explicitly creates a bound method of ``a``; storing or accessing it as ``a.hello`` does not make it aware that should be re-bound on access.

Comment: You can use copy.deepcopy which makes a deep copy instead of copy.copy which makes a shallow copy, see @MisterMiyagi message for why this happens. The better way to do it would be through class inheritance and override that function there.

Comment: Although it looks like a behavior specific to a patched method, it's really just https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794244/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-python in disguise.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and explanation. @mananony you're right, I'll create a decorator that'll subclass the original class and override the method in it. I already tested it and it works just fine since the method becomes unbound. I'll write the answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @MisterMiyagi, the method created through `types.MethodType` is bound to the object `a` (it can only be called on `a`) and assigning it to object `c` (by copying) does not make it unbound.

The solution outlined by @mananony is to subclass `Person` and override the method in the subclass. This way the method will remain unbound, linked to the subclass and can be called with any object of type `MeanInner`.

I put the subclass in a decorator because in my real code `Person` actually represents a lot of classes with `hello` method and I want to be able to change all of them.

```py
def mean(person_cls):
    class MeanInner(person_cls):
        def hello(self, n):
            print(id(self), f"{n} times mean hello in {self.lang}")

    return MeanInner


a = mean(Person)('English')
c = copy.copy(a)
c.lang = 'German'
print(id(a), id(c))  # 140407794133424 140407794133536
a.hello(2)  # 140407794133424 2 times mean hello in English
c.hello(2)  # 140407794133536 2 times mean hello in German
```

Comment: Just a thought but instead of doing it like this, would it not be better to create a single class "MeanInner" outside a function, and then instantiate that one instead of 'Person' ? that would probably be cleaner than monkey patching all instances... Creating a new class every time sounds overkill and you may have to rethink the way your code works. Instead of doing copy.copy you should just create a new instance of that class.

Comment: You're right in most cases it would help. However as I described in the question I don't have control over the copying since it is happening in library code.
I also could've used a simple subclass (as in your solution) but in my case `Person` actually represents a lot of different classes so a decorator pattern is cleaner than subclassing all of them. Also I need some of the instances of a particular class to "be mean" and some not so that's why I used a specific class for each mean instance.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using copy.copy you should probably use classes as they are intended to be used, and create new instances of an inherited class.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, lang):
        self.lang = lang

    def hello(self, n):
        print(id(self), f"{n} times hello in {self.lang}")
        
class MeanInner(Person):
    def hello(self, n):
        print(id(self), f"{n} times mean hello in {self.lang}")


a = MeanInner('English')
c = MeanInner('German')
print(id(a), id(c))  # 139980069269760 139980069269664
a.hello(2)  # 139980069269760 2 times mean hello in English
c.hello(2)  # 139980069269664 2 times mean hello in German
```