# How to copy a bytearray

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

Assigning a bytearray to another variable seems to simply assign the address to the bytearray and does not really create a copy. Here is a sample code:

```
a = bytearray(b'000000000000000011111111')
b = a
print ('a =', a)
print('b =', b)
a[0] = ord('1')
print ('a =', a)
print ('b =', b)
```

with the following output:

```
a = bytearray(b'000000000000000011111111')
b = bytearray(b'000000000000000011111111')
a = bytearray(b'100000000000000011111111')
b = bytearray(b'100000000000000011111111')
```

So, when variable a is modified, b gets implicitly modified too. How to copy the contents of variable a to another variable?

Comment: Generic version of this question: [How can I create a copy of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4794244/4518341) The accepted answer doesn't really apply to a bytearray, but [Aaron Hall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46939443/4518341) does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `bytearray.copy` method:

```
b = a.copy()
```

Slicing will also create a copy:

```
b = a[:]
```