# Python: assigning to variable also assigns to class attribute?

Tags: python, class, pygame, variable-assignment, class-attributes

I haven't found any similar questions and I'm struggling to understand what my code is doing right now.

I'm writing a small puzzle game with Pygame, which is also my first foray into object-oriented programming. Pygame provides `Rect` objects to define a portion of the screen (with attributes like `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, and so on). Since my game is text-heavy, I created an object `Region` to group a `Rect` object with a `font` object and some color information for when I need to blit to screen:

```
    def __init__(self, rect, bg_color, font, font_color):
        self.rect = rect
        self.bg_color = bg_color
        self.font = font
        self.font_color = font_color
```

I then created a `Layout` class that would hold a collection of `Region` objects, along with a centralized color palette and some methods for redrawing screen elements. Since this game only has one "board," I only need one `Layout` object, so I made the `Region` objects class attributes:

```
   ...
   progress_box: region(pygame.Rect(5, 340, 275, 10),
                                   colors["white"],
                                   pygame.font.SysFont('arialblack', 12),
                                   colors["black"])
```

(Snipped out the other Region objects for readability.)

Later in the code, I have a function that draws a progress bar in `progress_box` like so:

```
def display_progress(score, viz, max_score):
    progress = round(score/max_score, 4)
    progress_bar = region(viz.boxes["progress_box"].rect, "gold", None, None)
    progress_bar.rect.width = int(progress * progress_box.rect.width)
    viz.box_blit(progress_bar) ##viz is my layout object
```

What should happen, as I understand it, is that `progress_bar` copies the `rect` attribute from `progress_box` object, but then I reset the `width` attribute to a percentage of the `progress_box.rect` width. I'm not assigning anything to `progress_box` itself, and `progress_bar` is a `Region` object not connected to the `Layout` class, so I assumed that `progress_box.rect.width` would remain constant over every loop.

Instead, whatever value I assign to `progress_bar.rect.width` is also assigned to `progress_box.rect.width`. That means, of course, that on the first pass through the loop, both those values are set to 0 because the player's score is 0, and after that they can never change.

The function works as intended if I change `progress_bar.rect.width = int(progress * progress_box.rect.width)` to `progress_bar.rect.width = int(progress * 275)`, but that doesn't explain to me why the variable is changing when I don't assign anything directly to it. I understand that these attributes are only initialized once, so any change to a class attribute will persist through every loop -- I'm just not sure why it's changing in the first place.

Comment: *"What should happen, as I understand it, is that progress_bar copies the rect attribute from progress_box object"* Nope, a direct object assignment like that does not perform a "deep copy" so modifying one object will also mutate the other. [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794244/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, @CoryKramer, that was not clear from the reference material I was using!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Cory Kramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/cory-kramer) already pointed this out in his comment, but wanted to expand on it a bit for anyone who comes across this.

The [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) section of the official docs gives a good explanation of how objects and object references work in Python.

> An object’s identity never changes once it has been created; you may think of it as the object’s address in memory. The ‘is’ operator compares the identity of two objects; the id() function returns an integer representing its identity.

So you can think about when you're assigning objects to different variables or attributes, you are actually assigning a reference to the object, not a copy of the object.

---

You can make a quick example in the repl to show this off:

```py
class Region:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

class Layout:
    def __init__(self, region):
        self.region = region
```

```py
my_region = Region(width=5, height=5)
layout1 = Layout(my_region)
layout2 = Layout(my_region)
```

So I created a single `Region` instance and passed it into two separate `Layout` instances. As expected, the widths are the same initially:

```py
layout1.region.width
Out: 5

layout2.region.width
Out: 5
```

Then change the width of the region in `layout1`:

```py
layout1.region.width = 10
```

And checking the widths again, you'll see both changed:

```py
layout1.region.width
Out: 10

layout2.region.width
Out: 10
```

You can also check the memory addresses of each layout region to confirm that they are actually pointing to the same slot in memory (they are the same object essentially):

```py
id(layout1.region)
Out: 140631994345120

id(layout2.region)
Out: 140631994345120
```

---

Copying and equality [can be a big topic](https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/), but in short you should check out the [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=copy#module-copy).

For example, if you wanted truly unique objects in that example above, you could either create unique `Region` instances for each `Layout` instance, or you could make a copy if you aren't able to instantiate new objects, needing to just duplicate an existing one:

```py
"""
Unique instances of Region.
"""

layout1 = Layout(Region(width=5, height=5))
layout2 = Layout(Region(width=5, height=5))

# unique references in memory

id(layout1.region)
Out: 140631995857072

id(layout2.region)
Out: 140631995436384
```

```py
"""
Copy's of an existing Region instance.
"""

import copy

region = Region(width=5, height=5)

layout1 = Layout(copy.copy(region))
layout2 = Layout(copy.copy(region))

# unique references in memory

id(region)
Out: 140631993964480

id(layout1.region)
Out: 140631995585920

id(layout2.region)
Out: 140631995588176
```