# copy a list in python

Tags: python, list

Please what's the difference between this two codes in python:

```
white=[2,4,8,9]
black = white
```

and

```
white=[2,4,8,9]
black = white[:]
```

thank you so much.

Comment: Try modifying white or black after the copy and see if the other changes.

Comment: This article has been published recently and is exactly what you're looking for - http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 8):

The first copies a reference to the list `white` to the variable `black`

So any changes to `black` will also alter `white` and visa versa

Think of it as an alias or nickname for `white`

The second copies the contents of the list `white` to the variable `black` and is perhaps better written like this

```
black = list(white)
```

In this case there is no connection between the two variables `black` and `white` as it is the contents of `white` that are copied and not a reference to `white` itself.

Extra to take into account the relevant comment below (thanks Jon Clements): you can read more about deep copies vs shallow copies here [Understanding dict.copy() - shallow or deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep)

Comment: *The second copies the contents* -> The second creates a shallow copy of the contents...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `id()` and `is` to see the difference in Python shell:

```
>>> white=[2,4,8,9]
>>> black = white
>>> id(white)
41026064
>>> id(black)
41026064
>>> black is white
True
```

`black` and `white` point to the same object, so they are not two things, they are one.  When you make a slice (or shallow) copy, a new object is created.

```
>>> white=[2,4,8,9]
>>> black = white[:]
>>> id(white)
41026064
>>> id(black)
41025904
>>> black is white
False
```

Answer (score 0):

As an additional data point, Python 3.3 added the `copy` method as a readable alternative to the slicing syntax. So `white.copy()` also creates a shallow copy of the list `white`