# Same dict object in List of dict Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Why in Python, use of n * [dict()] to create nested dictionary causes same dictionary object?

```
>>> d = [(111, 2222), (3333, 4444), (555, 666)]
>>> d
[(111, 2222), (3333, 4444), (555, 666)]
>>> x = len(d) * [dict().copy()][:]
>>> x
[{}, {}, {}]
>>> x[0]['x'] = 'u'
>>> x # All entries of x gets modified
[{'x': 'u'}, {'x': 'u'}, {'x': 'u'}]
>>> 
>>> x = [dict(), dict(), dict()]
>>> x
[{}, {}, {}]
>>> x[0]['x'] = 'u'
>>> x # only one entry of x gets modified
[{'x': 'u'}, {}, {}]
>>>
```

Comment: Here is how `dict.copy` copy dict. [Understanding dict.copy() - shallow or deep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep)

Answer (score 5):

In `x = len(d) * [dict().copy()][:]`, the `dict` function is run only once.  Consequently, all three dictionaries are the same.  If you want three different dictionaries, you need to run it three times, e.g.:

```
>>> x = [dict() for i in range(3)]
>>> x
[{}, {}, {}]
>>> x[0]['x'] = 'u'
>>> x
[{'x': 'u'}, {}, {}]
>>>
```

#### More

Python cannot multiply a list until *after* it has *created* the list.  Thus, when `3 * [dict()]` is executed, `dict` is evaluated first and then the multiplication is performed.  The same is true of `3*[int(1)]` but notice a difference that may seem confusing at first:

```
>>> x = 3*[int(1)]
>>> x
[1, 1, 1]
>>> x[0] = 2
>>> x
[2, 1, 1]
```

Superficially, this might seem inconsistent with the case of the multiplied list of dictionaries.  The difference here is that the assignment statement `x[0] = 2` does *not* modify the properties of `x[0]`; it *replaces* `x[0]` with a new element.  Consequently, the result is different.

The concept of replacement also applies to dictionaries.  Consider:

```
>>> x = 3 * [dict()]
>>> x
[{}, {}, {}]
>>> x[0] = dict(x='u')
>>> x
[{'x': 'u'}, {}, {}]
```

Even thought the three dictionaries in `x` start out as the same, the statement `x[0] = dict(x='u')` replaces the first dictionary with a new one.

Comment: Then `int(1)` in `3*[int(1)]` will run only once? I don't know what happens applying `N*` to list. Please tell me if you know.

Comment: @user2931409 Yes, `int` will run only once in that case.  The list has to be created before multiplication can be performed.  However, see the expanded answer for more on this.

Comment: I did understand it! When I execute `x=3*[int(1)];x[0]=2` ,it simply overwrite `x[0]`. That's why `x[1]` and `x[2]` are not affected. I didn't notice that. Thanks for teaching me detail.