# A Python function between copy() and deepcopy()

Tags: python

My response can be considered a follow-up to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep).

I have a dictionary that contains lists of objects.  I want some function in between the `copy` and `deepcopy` functions in the `copy` module. I want something that performs a deep copy on built-in Python structures and primitives (integers, sets, strings, lists, etc.) but doesn't produce a deep copy of user-made objects (or non-primitive, non-aggregate objects).

It seems I might need to modify the `__deepcopy__` method of my objects, but I'm not quite sure how to do this properly.  A solution that does not modify an object's `__deepcopy__` method is also preferable, in the event that I want to make a deep copy of the object in a future script.

Assume this is the top of my Python file:

```
import copy

class Obj():
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i = i
        pass

d = {0:Obj(5),1:[Obj(6)],2:[]}
d2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
```

As examples, I'll list some code snippets below, along with the actual output and the desired output.

**Snippet 1**

```
d[1][0].i=7
print "d[1][0].i:",d[1][0].i,"d2[1][0].i:",d2[1][0].i
```

- Actual Output: `d[1][0].i: 7 d2[1][0].i: 6`
- Desired Output `d[1][0].i: 7 d2[1][0].i: 7`

**Snippet 2**

```
d[0].i = 6
print "d[0].i:",d[0].i,"d2[0].i:",d2[0].i
```

- Actual Output: `d[0].i: 6 d2[0].i: 5`
- Desired Output `d[0].i: 6 d2[0].i: 6`

Comment: I think you'll have to substitute `__deepcopy__` or make a method of your own

Comment: do you absolutely _need_ copies?  often the best way to solve a problem like this is to avoid copying anything in the first place.

Comment: @Eevee: The problem I'm solving an iterative one where I search through a tree of possible solutions.  I build a solution incrementally (recursion is too slow for me).  The root state is a dictionary of lists, and each list contains an object I defined.  I need to modify the lists of temporary dictionaries I define during iteration, without modifying the root.  I also need to store references to the objects instead of the objects themselves (for sake of space and functionality).

Comment: in that case you could just do `d2 = {k: v.copy() for (k, v) in d.items()}` — you know the shape of your data, so just make an explicit copy of that shape, instead of writing a more complex (and slow, and buggy) general-purpose solution

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, straight from the docs:

```
import copy

class Obj:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return self
```

Your last example doesn't seem right, as `d3` is a shallow copy of `d`, therefore the list indexed by `2` should remain the same reference.

To allow for deep copying as an option, you could set some attribute in the object, and check for that in `__deepcopy__`.

Comment: Good call on d3 and Snippet 3!  Not sure what I was thinking when I wrote those :).  I just removed that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how the (pure python) `deepcopy` and `copy` methods are made [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r27a4/Lib/copy.py). You can try to make a simpler one for your specific objects or try to modify the "original".

You can also modify the `__deepcopy__` method of your objects to return simply `self`, but that might affect their behavior - if you'd like to `deepcopy` them later, of course, but also if you use some external libraries, e.g. debuggers or GUI.