# Python duplicate a python-igraph

Tags: python, reference, duplicates, igraph

I have a python-igraph and need to make two copies of it and change each of the copies without changing the other one. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
copy1 = fullGraph
copy2 = fullGraph
```

But it seems that this is not the correct way of doing it since whatever I change in copy1, the same thing happen to copy2 (like deleting an edge). I was wondering what is the best way to make a copy of the main graph.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign statements do not copy objects in Python. You might want to use
[`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function.

More details about `copy.shallow()` and `copy.deepcopy()` can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep/3975388#3975388) answer

Also `Graph` objects have inherited [`copy` method](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#copy) which makes a shallow copies. You can use it like:

```
copy1 = fullGraph.copy()
copy2 = fullGraph.copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

A `graph` objects has a `copy` method which creates a shallow copy.
Use it like:

```
myGraphShallowCopied = myGraph.copy()
```

Note that the graph is duplicated, but objects stored in the graph are not.
This means, that if you change a graph, only the copy (or the original) get changed. If you change an object in the graph, it will change for both the copied graph as the original graph as they reference the same object.

If you want a true copy you can use `copy.deepcopy()` like:

```
from copy import deepcopy
myGraphDeepCopied = deepcopy(myGraph)
```

Note that this can be (depending on the objects stored in the graph) much slower than creating a shallow copy.

A clear explanation between the difference of a shallow and deepcopy can be found here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep/3975388#3975388).