# Why setting a dict shallow copy to itself?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, shallow-copy

I think it's a bit weird question to ask.
The thing is that while I was studying some parts of django code I came across something I've never seen before.
According to [Copy Difference Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) and
[It's usage in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep) we can create two dictionary with same reference.

The question is what is the purpose of setting a shallow copy of a dictionary to itself?
Code:

> django.template.backends.base

```
params = {
   'BACKEND' = 'Something',
   'DIRS' = 'Somthing Else',
}
params = params.copy()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant part or [django.template.backends.base.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/backends/base.py) looks like this:

```
class BaseEngine(object):

    # Core methods: engines have to provide their own implementation
    #               (except for from_string which is optional).

    def __init__(self, params):
        """
        Initializes the template engine.
        Receives the configuration settings as a dict.
        """
        params = params.copy()
        self.name = params.pop('NAME')
        self.dirs = list(params.pop('DIRS'))
        self.app_dirs = bool(params.pop('APP_DIRS'))
        if params:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Unknown parameters: {}".format(", ".join(params)))
```

The dictionary `params` in `def __init__(self, params):` will be copied to a **new** dictionary `params = params.copy()`. It just uses the same name. Therefore, the old object cannot be accessed any more via this name. In the next steps the new local dictionary is modified but the original one stays unchanged.

Doing `self.params = params`, instead of `params = params.copy()` would have a very different effect. In this case `self.params`would be just a second name for the object behind `params`. Since it is a dictionary and mutable, all changes to `self.params` would effect `params`. `params.pop('NAME')` removes the key `NAME'`
from the dictionary. Actually, there is a check that it is empty: `params.pop('NAME')`.

Comment: Well from what you said I understand they just copied the dict to use it but not to change it so why not:  
`self.params = params`  
instead?

Comment: They do change it. Added a section about this to my answer.

Comment: now I'v got it...  
in order to use a dict without changing it we use copy().
And thats not all...
self.params wouldn't make a new variable for the class... it just copy the var to use it inside that specific object and still it's the same object.