# Issue when building a nested dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python

I wanted to build a nested dictionary based on a text file. for example. (text.txt)

```
...
hostA           hostA.testing.com               192.168.1.101
hostB           hostB.testing.com               192.168.1.102
...
```

Ideally, I want to get the following nested dictionary

```
...
{'hostA': {'FQHN': 'hostA.testing.com', 'IP': '192.168.1.101'}, 'hostB': {'FQHN': 'hostB.testing.com', 'IP': '192.168.1.102'}}
...
```

So I made the following Python code:

```
myinnerdict={}
myouterdict={}

def main():
    my_fh = open('text.txt', 'r')
    for line in my_fh:
        newline = line.strip().split()    # get ride of the '\n' and make it a inner list .
        #print(newline)
        myinnerdict['FQHN']=newline[1]
        myinnerdict['IP']=newline[2]
        #print(myinnerdict)
        #print(newline[0])
        myouterdict[newline[0]]=myinnerdict
    print(myouterdict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
...
```

however, beyond my understanding , when I ran it I got this result:

```
...
{'hostA': {'FQHN': 'hostB.testing.com', 'IP': '192.168.1.102'}, 'hostB': {'FQHN': 'hostB.testing.com', 'IP': '192.168.1.102'}}
...
```

which is not what I wanted , I don't know what I missed, please kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing the same variable for the dictionary. As `myouterdict` is storing the reference to the variable `myinnerdict` instead of the actual data, therefore, both of them are the same. For example, try this:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> b = {"my a variable": a}
>>> b
{'my a variable': {}}
>>> a["asdf"] = 3
>>> b
{'my a variable': {'asdf': 3}}
```

As you can see, `b` is storing the reference of `a` and not the empty dict data of `a`. What you need to do is [`.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#set.copy) it over (Note that `.copy()` does not copy the contents of the dict but makes a new reference read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep)):

```
myinnerdict = {}
myouterdict = {}

def main():
    my_fh = open('text.txt', 'r')
    for line in my_fh:
        newline = line.strip().split()

        myinnerdict['FQHN'] = newline[1]
        myinnerdict['IP'] = newline[2]
        # Note this copy here
        myouterdict[newline[0]] = myinnerdict.copy()
    print(myouterdict)
    # Remember to close the file!
    my_fh.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Anyways, you could also just immediately assign a newly created dict object instead of using a variable:

```
mydict = {}

def main():
    my_fh = open('test.txt', 'r')
    for line in my_fh:
        newline = line.strip().split()
        mydict[newline[0]] = {"FQHN": newline[1], "IP": newline[2]}
    print(mydict)
    my_fh.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are reusing the same dict object for the `innerdict`. You need create a new dict object within your loop:

```
myouterdict={}

def main():
    my_fh = open('text.txt', 'r')
    for line in my_fh:
        myinnerdict={}
        newline = line.strip().split()    # get ride of the '\n' and make it a inner list .
        #print(newline)
        myinnerdict['FQHN']=newline[1]
        myinnerdict['IP']=newline[2]
        #print(myinnerdict)
        #print(newline[0])
        myouterdict[newline[0]]=myinnerdict
    print(myouterdict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```