# Python - how to pass a dictionary into defaultdict as value and not as a reference

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, pass-by-reference, defaultdict

So say that I have a dictionary with a default value of another dictionary

```
attributes = { 'first_name': None, 'last_name': None, 'calls': 0 }
accounts = defaultdict(lambda: attributes)
```

The problem is that the default dictionary that I pass into defaultdict (attributes) is passed as a reference. How can I pass it as a value? So that changing the values in one key doesn't change the values in other keys

For example -

```
accounts[1]['calls'] = accounts[1]['calls'] + 1
accounts[2]['calls'] = accounts[2]['calls'] + 1
print accounts[1]['calls'] # prints 2
print accounts[2]['calls'] # prints 2
```

I want each of them to print 1, since I only incremented their respective values for 'calls' once.

Comment: You have to explicitly make a copy if that is what you want. Passing parameters always is like passing a reference.

Comment: Python has one and only one evaluation strategy: [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

Comment: You will like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep/3975388#3975388

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
accounts = defaultdict(attributes.copy)
```

Since Python 3.3 `lists`s [also have `copy` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) so you can use it the same way as above with `defaultdict`s when you need a dict with a list as a default value.

Comment: Yep! The factory can be any function that returns the value you want to use for missing keys (as long as it can be called without arguments), `attributes.copy` is just such a function!

Answer (score 3):

I really like warvariuc's solution. However,  remember, you are not passing a `dict` into `defaultdict`... that would result in a `TypeError`, because that argument must be a *callable*. You could have just used a literal in a lambda. Or better yet, define a helper function:

```
>>> def attribute():
...     return { 'first_name': None, 'last_name': None, 'calls': 0 }
...
>>> accounts = defaultdict(attribute)
>>> accounts[1]['calls'] = accounts[1]['calls'] + 1
>>> accounts[2]['calls'] = accounts[2]['calls'] + 1
>>> print(accounts[1]['calls'])
1
>>> print(accounts[2]['calls'])
1
```