# Create new column throws Pandas error despite following .loc recommendation

Tags: python, pandas

Coming from R, I naively tried

```
dfE_fitted['E_after'] = dfE_fitted['E_before']
```

That gave me

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

---

Fair enough, I'll try that then:

```
dfE_fitted.loc[:,'E_after'] = dfE_fitted['E_before']
```

This gives me

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:337: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:517: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

---

What am I doing horribly wrong?

Comment: Before: `Dem-Dexc  Aem-Dexc  Aem-Aexc       S       E  E_before  transition_frame                     filename  state`

    After: `Dem-Dexc  Aem-Dexc  Aem-Aexc       S       E  E_before  transition_frame                     filename  state  E_after`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't how you are doing your assignment.  It's how you constructed `dfE_fitted`.  You constructed it in such a way so as to be a "copy" of something else.  The recommendation to use `.loc` is intended to be used in the construction of `dfE_fitted`.  Even then, using `.loc` isn't a guarantee.  You can still have a "is_copy" flag after using `.loc`

However, I can't see how you did that.  Best I can do is recommend that you do

```
dfE_fitted = dfE_fitted.copy()
```

This will detangle the "copy" relationship and you can proceed to assign as you were.

```
dfE_fitted['E_after'] = dfE_fitted['E_before']
```

---

**Working example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2], E_before=[3, 4], E_after=[5, 6]))

# Notice how I constructed this
dfE_fitted = df[['E_before']]
```

Then I try

```
dfE_fitted['E_after'] = dfE_fitted['E_before']
```

I get

[image]

However, had I constructed `dfE_fitted` like this:

```
# Notice I used `.loc` like what was recommended
dfE_fitted = df.loc[:, ['E_before']]
```

I can do the following with no warning:

```
dfE_fitted['E_after'] = dfE_fitted['E_before']
```

You can tell if a dataframe is a "copy" by looking at its `is_copy` attribute.  If it is a copy, it will return a

```
<weakref at 0x1188d94f8; to 'DataFrame' at 0x1184bf898>
```

Which evaluates to `True`

```
bool(dfE_fitted.is_copy)

True
```

Otherwise, if it isn't a "copy" it is `None` and evaluates to `False`

Comment: By "construct", do you mean that perhaps my initial definition in my code `dfE_fitted = df_all` is causing problems?

Comment: If that was indeed how you created the name `dfE_fitted`, I'd do `dfE_fitted = df_all.copy()`

Comment: Pandas tracks to see if your current dataframe is a view or copy of another dataframe.  If it is, it's going to warn you when you do something that might alter that relationship.  It tracks that relationship with the `is_copy` attribute.  Most often this warning is encountered when people didn't expect it.  They had no idea there dataframe was a view or copy of another.  The easiest way to fix that is to explicitly make the dataframe you are working independent of any other dataframe by setting it to be a copy of itself.

Comment: Deleted my old comment, as I just stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep and now I'm in doubt. Wouldn't `deepcopy` be preferable then?

Comment: [**copy**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) is the documentation.  You'll notice there is a `deep` parameter which is set to `True` by default.  Also notice that you're linked Q&A is for `dict.copy`.  Pandas handles copy itself with `pd.DataFrame.copy`

Comment: My my my, would you look at that. It all makes sense now. Thanks.