# Set and Get attributes in Bunch type object

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, bunch

For simplicity to parse/create JSON, machine learning applications usually uses the `Bunch` object, e.g. https://github.com/dsc/bunch/blob/master/bunch/__init__.py

When getting, there's a nested EAFP idiom that checks through the `dict.get()` function and then trying to access it with dictionary square bracket syntax, i.e.

```
class Bunch(dict):
    def __getattr___(self, k):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, k)
        except AttributeError:
            try: 
                 return self[k]
            except KeyError:
                 raise AttributeError
```

And when trying to set an attribute,

```
    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        try:
            # Throws exception if not in prototype chain
            object.__getattribute__(self, k)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                self[k] = v
            except:
                raise AttributeError(k)
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, k, v)
```

Seems like the `sklearn` implementation follows the same train of thought but has lesser checks https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed5584/sklearn/utils/__init__.py#L61

```
class Bunch(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(kwargs)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

    def __dir__(self):
        return self.keys()

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        # Bunch pickles generated with scikit-learn 0.16.* have an non
        # empty __dict__. This causes a surprising behaviour when
        # loading these pickles scikit-learn 0.17: reading bunch.key
        # uses __dict__ but assigning to bunch.key use __setattr__ and
        # only changes bunch['key']. More details can be found at:
        # https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6196.
        # Overriding __setstate__ to be a noop has the effect of
        # ignoring the pickled __dict__
        pass
```

The nested EAFP seems a little hard to maintain, my questions here are:

- Is there a simpler way to handle get and set functions for Bunch data objects?
- Are there any other Dict like object that allows mutability between attributes and keys?
- How should Bunch object's `.update()` function work, shallow or deep copying? Or just let the default `dict.update()` do what it does?  [Understanding dict.copy() - shallow or deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep)

Comment: Too many questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucky for you, all objects have an internal dict-like object that manages the attributes of the object (this is in the `__dict__` attribute).  To do what you're asking, you just need to make the class use itself as the `__dict__` object:

```py
class Bunch(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__ = self
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Usage:

```py
>>> b = Bunch()
>>> b.foo = 3
>>> b["foo"]
3
>>> b["foo"] = 5
>>> b.foo
5
>>> b["bar"] = 1
>>> b.bar
1
```

Comment: This is wonderfully succinct. I'm wondering why this wasn't the implementation that sklearn went with rather than overriding the attr methods.