# Are shallow and deep copy identical for mutable objects containing immutable values?

Tags: python, deep-copy, shallow-copy

From reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975376/understanding-dict-copy-shallow-or-deep) it seems that for Python dictionaries and lists where values are mutable objects, shallow and deep copy work differently. However, if the Python dictionary or list is simply one where the values are immutable (i.e. string, integer etc.), are shallow and deep copy equivalent?

Comment: Not necessarily. A tuple is immutable, but may contain mutable values.

Comment: @chepner Good point, but for strings or integers it would be true?